# What is your preferred way to produce charts in a Ruby on Rails 3 web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I know this question has been asked 3 years ago, so I was wondering is there anything new and/or better than it was 3 years ago.

Currently, I am using GoogleVisualr ( http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/ ) and I like it...it is simple and easy, but it lacks radar charts :(

So, I was wondering is there any other free and easy charting solutions? Javascript or flash is good for me, but I need to have radar charts.

Thank you
Dorijan

Comment: have you seen http://www.fusioncharts.com? In that flash charts are free but for js charts you need to pay.

Comment: yes...I looked at them, but free version does not have Radar Charts :( http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/compare/

Answer (score 1):

I use and recommend [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It's not free, but it works well and has lots of features. Also, it's very well documented and has tons of working code examples on the site.

Development licenses (I believe) are free so you can try it out at no cost then pay only if you decide to use it. The price isn't too high either considering the time it saves.

Comment: I've used Highcharts as well, it works great if you want something to  drop in. I've also used Highstock, which has some interesting features that are not available in Highcharts. You can also use non -stock and non-financial data with Highstock.

Comment: Not sure what your hourly rate is, but having something that saves you lots of time may be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Check following code,

```
  <html>
      <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["imagechart"]});
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataTable.addColumn('number');
            dataTable.addColumn('number');
            dataTable.addRows([
              [100,10],
              [80,20],
              [60,30],
              [30,40],
              [25,50],
              [20,60],
              [10,70],
            ]);

            var chart = new google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('radar_div'));

            var options = {cht: 'rs', chco: '00FF00,FF00FF', chg: '25.0,25.0,4.0,4.0', chm: 'B,FF000080,0,1.0,5.0|B,FF990080,1,1.0,5.0',};
            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id='radar_div'></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[Refer](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/genericimagechart) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)?

Also found someone who has [shared] (https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/protovis/GsFB1l1Mo_g/geLerhwvbdQJ) their code to create radar graphs using [protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/) which still available.

Finally, someone else's [sample] (https://gist.github.com/1630683) of radar graphs using d3.